# Is there a way to improve Endnote record consistency?

Tags: tools, citations

I am required to use Endnote to manage citations. When I find an article, I am expected to create an Endnote record for it, and we have some internal guidelines as to which fields we consider mandatory (basically the ones needed for proper scientific citations).

Tools like Google scholar allow for a semi-automated workflow, where I can download a record which supposedly has the full bibliographical information on the text. But in fact, the information is often low quality, and I have to clean it up per hand. Inconsistent use of initials, authors sometimes given as `First name Last name`, sometimes as `Last name, First name` and similar problems abound. Then there is the problem of missing fields.

Is there something - an add-on or a Web service - which can perform some automatic cleanup? For example, it could search for the ISBN given the title, or vice versa, the way Calibre does. It could fill in a publisher based on the journal's name, sparing me hunting publisher names all over the Internet. I understand that such a system isn't perfect, but even if it fetched the possible matches and showed me asking for confirmation, this would be a huge improvement over the manual process.

If this isn't possible, is there another tool which supports it and has a reasonable Endnote compatibility allowing for seamless import and export? I am specifically interested in bibtex and other TeX compatible tools, because I plan to transition to TeX for publications in the near future.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not that familiar with Endnote, but I did find this site. Looking over it, I think there might be something here that would help you out.

[Endnotes plugins](http://www.csu.edu.au/division/library/research/endnote/getting/plugins)

Answer (score 0):

Endnote is truly dreadful.  I'd recommend using [Zotero](http://zotero.org) to collect the data, then clean it up before exporting to RIS format,and then importing that into Endnote.